# Using ESP32 to program a SAM

Tags: esp32

I'm building a device that will feature the ESP32 as the main microcontroller, and have a SAMD10 onboard for taking care of the precision timer stuff that TC's and TCC's are oh so good at. I would like the ESP32 to be capable of updating the firmware on the SAMD10 by downloading a pre-compiled file over WiFi, and then flashing it to the SAMD10 over UART.

Is this possible? Would I need a special bootloader to do this? I've looked and looked but amazingly nobody seems to have documented this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use a bootloader for this. This is a standard way of updating firmware after "production" either way if the MCU has a capabilities for bootloader (SAMD10 includes this).

Microchip actually provides a secure bootloader for SAMD10 already. Check out [AN2570](https://www.microchip.com//wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en603279), they include source code & documentation.

Another way might be writing your own bootloader or search for other publicly available bootloaders which will suit your needs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the process for uploading? How does the ESP32 put the device into bootloader mode, and how is the data sent?

Comment: @DavidCutting if you are writing your own bootloader, it's up to you to decide how it will be called. As for the one provided by Microchip, their document describes how it's entered and rest.